# Restricting a monad to a type class

Tags: haskell, types, monads, typeclass

In Haskell, is there a way to restrict a monad `M a` so that `a` satisfy a type class constraint?

I am translating the [probabilistic modeling example](http://github.com/namin/spots/tree/master/probabilisticModeling/README.markdown) from [F#](http://github.com/namin/spots/tree/master/probabilisticModeling/probabilisticModeling.fsx) to [Haskell](http://github.com/namin/spots/tree/6c5a3b78e8f5f559900bade7629fab0edcf225e8/probabilisticModeling/probabilisticModeling.hs). However, in Haskell, I omitted `support` because it would change `data Distribution a` to `data (Ord a) => Distribution a`. With this change, I get the following error:

```
...probabilisticModeling.hs:42:13:
    Could not deduce (Ord a) from the context ()
      arising from a use of `always'
                   at ...probabilisticModeling.hs:42:13-18
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord a) to the context of the type signature for `return'
    In the expression: always
    In the definition of `return': return = always
    In the instance declaration for `Monad Distribution'
```

Indeed, the type of `always`/`return` is: `(Ord a) => a -> Distribution a`. Is there a way I can have a monad `Distribution`, but force the constraint `(Ord a)` on this monad? I tried:

```
instance Monad Distribution where
    (>>=) = bind
    return :: (Ord a) => a -> Distribution a = always
```

But I get the error:

```
...probabilisticModeling2.hs:48:4:
    Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declarations
      return :: (Ord a) => a -> Distribution a = always
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So it there a way to have a monad `M a`, but restrict the `a` with a constraint such as `Ord a`?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that you can do this with the `ConstraintKinds` language extension and the `ConstraintKinds` package, see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConstraintKinds-1.3.0/docs/Control-ConstraintKinds-Monad.html) for a constrained monad, and [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConstraintKinds-1.3.0/docs/Control-ConstraintKinds-Functor.html#t:FunctorConstraint) the `FunctorConstraint`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding of this is that you simply cannot, because a monad is meant to be generalized over all types, not some restricted subset of types such as `(Ord a)`.

Instead of restricting the monadic type `M a`, you can simply restrict functions which use that monadic type, e.g.,

```
foo :: Ord a => Int -> M a
```

In fact, it is preferable to keep types as general as possible and use type classes only to restrict functions.

etc.

Answer (score 13):

It appears that I ran into a well-known problem in Haskell. I [found many workarounds](http://delicious.com/adnamin/haskell+restricted+monads) by [googling for "restricted monads"](http://www.google.ch/search?q=restricted+monads). [This solutions](http://hsenag.livejournal.com/11803.html) seems to be the least disruptive. Still, for my purposes, it seems overkill. I think I'll keep the `Distribution` monad general, and simplify a support via a restricted function, as suggested by Revolucent.

Comment: Is the "least disruptive" solution not just a particular case of free monad ? (I know that this solution has been published before the free monad craze).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Martin Erwig's library, PFP](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/pfp/):

> The PFP library is a collection of modules for Haskell that facilitates probabilistic functional programming, that is, programming with stochastic values. The probabilistic functional programming approach is based on a data type for representing distributions. A distribution represent the outcome of a probabilistic event as a collection of all possible values, tagged with their likelihood.