# haskell -- monad with values restricted to a typeclass

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restricting a monad to a type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379546/restricting-a-monad-to-a-type-class)

I want to write a Set monad that's similar to the List monad. However, this can't be done because Set requires its types to be ordered. Is there a way to create a monad that only takes values in a particular typeclass (say, Ord)? The code I want to write is

```
instance Monad Set.Set where
    return a = Set.singleton a
    -- set α, function (α -> set β)
    xs >>= f = Set.fold
        (\x s -> Set.union s (f x))
        Set.empty
        xs
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I guess SO only found the duplicate after I added the tags ... they should put the tag field before the description so the "possible duplicates" would get filtered better. Please add the rmonad link to the other question, it is very useful!