# What's the current status of restricted monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

Going back to at least the late 1990s there have been people wishing for the integration of [restricted monads](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#restricted-datatypes) into Haskell in a friendly way.

For example, without restricted monads you can't make an efficient monad out of `Set`, `Map` or [probability distributions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/probability/0.2.2/doc/html/Numeric-Probability-Distribution.html). Here's a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379546/restricting-a-monad-to-a-type-class) from a few years ago where someone else ran afoul of this problem.

There are various workarounds that people have come up with, including:

- Creating a [new type class](http://hsenag.livejournal.com/11803.html) for every possible restriction.
- Using [Template Haskell](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/15/data-set-monad-haskell-macros).
- Using [Constraint Kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127).

None of these approaches seem to be "canonical" however. I found a comment from Don Stewart on [this blog post](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/06/how-to-write-tolerably-efficient.html), in 2007, where he intimated that we were "quite close" to having restricted monads with [Indexed types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Indexed_types).

What is the current status? Is there now a 'canonical' way to do restricted monads? Or we are still living with workarounds?

Comment: I'd think with constraint kinds it's as canonical as it gets, they're just a bit too new for it to be the most _common_ solution yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a recent paper by Anders Persson, Emil Axelsson, and Josef Svenningson that shows a way to encode restricted monads.  I've forgotten the details, but I remember it was a nice paper.

> Persson, A. ; Axelsson, E. ; Svenningsson, J. (2011). [*Generic monadic constructs for embedded languages*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~josefs/publications/paper21_cameraready.pdf). IFL 2011, the 23rd Symposium on Implementation and Application of Functional Languages.

Comment: Thanks Norman. For anyone who's interested, you can get a copy of the paper from [Josef Svenningson's homepage](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~josefs/).

Answer (score 11):

Actually it is possible to obtain an efficient Set monad as a regular monad,
without any restrictions. In two distinct ways. The following article
explains both:

http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/set-monad.html

The article also points out that restricted monads are actually quite
restricted and preclude many monadic idioms. I conjecture that the
implementation methods are general and any restricted monad can be
turned into the usual one, without losing efficiency. So, it may seem
that we don't need restricted monads at all.

Comment: I actually already used the idea behind your efficient Set monad to build an efficient probability distribution monad (see https://github.com/chris-taylor/hs-probability/blob/master/src/Control/Probability/Bayes.hs) .. so thanks! I haven't thought about doing the same thing for other restricted monads, but I can't immediately see a reason why it wouldn't work.