# Class contraints for monads and monad functions

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to write a new monad that only can contain a Num.  When it fails, it returns 0 much like the Maybe monad returns Nothing when it fails.

Here is what I have so far:

```
data (Num a) => IDnum a = IDnum a

instance Monad IDnum where
  return x = IDnum x
  IDnum x >>= f  = f x
  fail :: (Num a) => String -> IDnum a
  fail _ = return 0
```

Haskell is complaining that there is

```
No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of `IDnum'
```

It suggests that I add a add (Num a) to the context of the type signature for each of my monad functions, but I tried that it and then it complains that they need to work "forall" a.

Ex:

```
Method signature does not match class; it should be
  return :: forall a. a -> IDnum a
In the instance declaration for `Monad IDnum'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Constructing efficient monad instances on `Set` (and other containers with constraints) using the continuation monad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12183656/1333025)

Answer (score 15):

The existing `Monad` typeclass expects your type to work for *every* possible type argument. Consider `Maybe`: in `Maybe a`, `a` is not constrained at all. Basically **you can't have a Monad with constraints**.

This is a fundamental limitation of how the `Monad` class is defined—I don't know of any way to get around it without modifying that.

This is also a problem for defining `Monad` instances for other common types, like `Set`.

In practice, this restriction is actually pretty important. Consider that (normally) functions are *not* instances of `Num`. This means that we could not use your monad to contain a function! This really limits important operations like `ap` (`<*>` from `Applicative`), since that depends on a monad containing a function:

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Your monad would not support many common uses and idioms we've grown to expect from normal monads! This would rather limit its utility.

Also, as a side-note, you should generally avoid using `fail`. It doesn't really fit in with the `Monad` typeclass: it's more of a historic accident. Most people agree that you should avoid it in general: it was just a hack to deal with failed pattern matches in do-notation.

That said, looking at how to define a restricted monad class is a great exercise for understanding a few Haskell extensions and learning some intermediate/advanced Haskell.

### Alternatives

With the downsides in mind, here are a couple of alternatives—replacements for the standard `Monad` class that *do* support restricted monads.

#### Constraint Kinds

I can think of a couple of possible alternatives. The most modern one would be taking advantage of the `ConstraintKind` extension in GHC, which lets you reify typeclass constraints as kinds. [This blog post](http://jeltsch.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/the-constraint-kind/) details how to implement a restricted monad using constraint kinds; once I've read it, I'll summarize it here.

The basic idea is simple: with `ConstraintKind`, we can turn our constrain (`Num a`) into a type. We can then have a new `Monad` class which contains this type as a member (just like `return` and `fail` are members) and allows use to overload the constraint with `Num a`. This is what the code looks like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies    #-}

module Main where

import Prelude hiding (Monad (..))

import GHC.Exts

class Monad m where
  type Restriction m a :: Constraint
  type Restriction m a = ()

  return :: Restriction m a => a -> m a
  (>>=)  :: Restriction m a => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  fail   :: Restriction m a => String -> m a

data IDnum a = IDnum a

instance Monad IDnum where
  type Restriction IDnum a = Num a
  return        = IDnum
  IDnum x >>= f = f x
  fail _        = return 0
```

#### RMonad

There is an existing library on hackage called [rmonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad) (for "restricted monad") which provides a more general typeclass. You could probably use this to write your desired monad instance. (I haven't used it myself, so it's a bit hard to say.)

It doesn't use the `ConstraintKinds` extension and (I believe) supports older versions of GHC. However, I think it's a bit ugly; I'm not sure that it's the best option any more.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Prelude hiding (Monad (..))

import Control.RMonad
import Data.Suitable

data IDnum a = IDnum a

data instance Constraints IDnum a = Num a => IDnumConstraints
instance Num a => Suitable IDnum a where
  constraints = IDnumConstraints

instance RMonad IDnum where
  return        = IDnum
  IDnum x >>= f = f x
  fail _        = withResConstraints $ \ IDnumConstraints -> return 0
```

### Further Reading

For more details, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599685/whats-the-current-status-of-restricted-monads).

Oleg has an article about this pertaining specifically to the Set monad, which might be interesting: ["How to restrict a monad without breaking it"](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/set-monad.html).

Finally, there are a couple of papers you could also read:

- [*The Constrained-Monad Problem*](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~neil/papers_and_talks/constrained-monad-problem.pdf)
- [*Generic Monadic Constructs for Embedded Languages*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~josefs/publications/paper21_cameraready.pdf)

Comment: There's [a basically just more modern version of rmonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConstraintKinds) that does use constraint kinds; doesn't seem exactly mature though. And there's my [constrained-categories project](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories), which handles this constraining stuff and much more, but rather more complicatedly (and it's still not stable enough to be usable).

Comment: Looks like your *Constraint Kinds* example was lacking one more restriction: the constraint of `(>>=)` should be `(Restriction m a, Restriction m b) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be brief, but here's another alternative to go along with Tikhon's. You can apply a codensity transformation to your type to basically get a free monad for it. Just use it (in the below code it's `IDnumM`) instead of your base type, then convert the final value to your base type at the end (in the below code, you would use `runIDnumM`). You can also inject your base type into the transformed type (in the below code, that would be `toIDnumM`).

A benefit of this approach is that it works with the standard `Monad` class.

```
data Num a => IDnum a = IDnum a

newtype IDnumM a = IDnumM { unIDnumM :: forall r. (a -> IDnum r) -> IDnum r }

runIDnumM :: Num a => IDnumM a -> IDnum a
runIDnumM (IDnumM n) = n IDnum

toIDnumM :: Num a => IDnum a -> IDnumM a
toIDnumM (IDnum x) = IDnumM $ \k -> k x

instance Monad IDnumM where
  return x = IDnumM $ \k -> k x
  IDnumM m >>= f = IDnumM $ \k -> m $ \x -> f x `unIDnumM` k
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this. One can use multiple functions. First, write one in the Maybe monad. The Maybe monad returns Nothing upon failure. Second, write a function that returns the Just value if not Nothing or some safe value if Nothing. Third, write a function that composes those two functions.

This produces the desired result while being much easier to write and understand.