# Defining a Monad with function depending on type of second argument of bind

Tags: haskell, monads

There's a Monad I'm trying to define, lets call it `MyData`.

Inside `MyData` there's some IO actions going on, there's a function `runMyMonad` that executes them.

Naturally I have to define `>>=`, with the following type signature:

```
instance Monad MyData ...
(>>=) :: MyData a -> (a -> MyData b) -> MyData b
```

I'd particularly like to define a Monad because I'd like users to be able to use "do" notation.

The thing is, to actually do what I want to do, I need to know some information that entirely depends on the type of `b`. Like the following:

```
myfunc (undefined :: b)
```

I could create a type class like so, but then there's a problem, my Monad no longer works because Monad requires `a` and `b` to be unrestricted.

I could create `MyData` like the following:

```
data MyData a where
  MyData :: (MyTypeClass a) => a -> a -> MyData a
```

Or something similar. That way when I pattern match on it, I get the typeclass for free. But I can only see this working on the first argument of `>>=`, as the second is wrapped up in a function.

So this is what I want to do:

a) Be able to apply a function that depends only on the type `b` in `>>=`.
b) Be able to use `do` notation.
c) Not affect other uses of `Monad`.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot write a `Monad` instance and have a class constraint which would allow you to get value-level information about a type in the bind function - you *can* but you must change the specification of `Monad`, obviously. If you just need do notation, maybe you should look into `RebindableSyntax`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the current status of restricted monads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599685/whats-the-current-status-of-restricted-monads).