# Using a monad to implicitly check refinement type well-formedness

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, refinement-type

While implementing a refinement type system, I need to put in checks to make sure the types are well-formed. For example, a type like `Num[100,0]` shouldn't happen, where `Num[lb,ub]` is the type of numbers larger than `lb` and smaller than `ub`. I then wrote:

```
-- FORMATION RULES

class RefTy t 
  where tyOK :: t -> Bool

instance RefTy Ty
  where tyOK (NumTy (n1, n2)) = n1 <= n2
        tyOK (CatTy cs) = isSet cs

{-
data WellFormed t = Valid t
                  | Invalid

instance Monad WellFormed
  where 
    (>>=) :: RefTy a => WellFormed a -> (a -> WellFormed b) -> WellFormed b
    Valid t >>= f 
            | tyOK t = f t
            | otherwise = Invalid
    Invalid >>= _ = Invalid
-}
```

Which got me into the known problem of "[restricted Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379546/restricting-a-monad-to-a-type-class)". The suggested answer is to have the `Wellformed` monad to be general but restrict the functions. However that would go back to adding the well-formed check everywhere. Is there a better way to get around?

Comment: And how would you define `return`/`pure`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, I don't think you actually want a monad, just the sugar that accompanies `do` notation. For example, have you thought about what your definition of `Applicative` will look like? Things get messy fast when you try to cheat your way through this.

Instead, if you want to use the `do`-notation, I suggest you use

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
```

which allows you to redefine, amongst other thing, the `(>>=)` and `return` used in desugaring a `do` block. You could then write something like:

```
myBind :: RefTy t1 => WellFormed t1 -> (t1 -> WellFormed t2) -> WellFormed t2
myBind Invalid _ = Invalid
myBind (Valid t) f | tyOK t = f t
                   | otherwise Invalid 

myReturn :: WellFormed t
myReturn t = Valid t
```

I'm not sure I agree with those definitions, but regardless you would then be able to write something like

```
do
  ...
  where (>>=) = myBind
        return = myReturn
```